# Extensions not supported on Azure App Service Environment

Tags: python, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We've recently moved from App Service to App Service Environment on Azure. We need Python 3.6 to run the web API. But we're not able to install the extensions. Are extensions disabled on App service environment. Azure by default offers Python 3.4.1. But few of the libraries need a minimum of 3.6.4 which is available as a extensions. Is there a workaround for this or are we limited to the default Python 3.4.1 available with Azure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed possible but took a bit of experimenting. I had to open the Kudu console from a VM which is inside the same VNet as the App Service Environment. From there on, it's a cake walk. You can also configure Web Jobs from the VM which is otherwise not possible from the portal.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't seen already, see article

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/

Microsoft says you can run newer versions, 3.4 is default purely to prevent breaking compatibility with existing sites.

Azure menu layout sometimes (annoyingly) changes from guides, but I was able to find it searching "Extensions" in the Menu for my App Service

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. But the question was for App Service Environment and not the generally available App Service. I've managed to solve this by using a VM which is on the same Vnet as the ASE. I'll add an answer